# C# var keyword usage

Tags: c#, styles

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What to use: var or object name type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236878/what-to-use-var-or-object-name-type)
>   [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c)
>   [What’s the point of the var keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209199/whats-the-point-of-the-var-keyword)
>   [Should I *always* favour implictly typed local variables in C# 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032/should-i-always-favour-implictly-typed-local-variables-in-c-3-0)

I have just installed a trial version of ReSharper to evaluate it for my company. One thing that I have noticed is it is suggesting that I change the following (made up example):

```
string s = "";
```

to

```
var s = "";
```

Is it best practice to use the var keyword rather than using the Object Type when declaring variables? What advantages does it give. For context I am a former Java developer who has just transitioned to the .Net works.

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032/should-i-always-favour-implictly-typed-local-variables-in-c-3-0

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209199/whats-the-point-of-the-var-keyword and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236878/what-to-use-var-or-object-name-type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c

Comment: It's still as good a question as when it was asked the last few times ...

Comment: @Unsliced: And lots of people gave good answers, including deeper insights - hence one should go and read them too.  Nobody downvoted anything.

Comment: The answers here didnt end up as good or as deep as the ones in the other thread, which is why people posted all of these see also comments.

Comment: @Unsliced: The question for me boils down to: "If there are 15 copies of this question with varying degrees of depth in the answers in 5 years time - is that better or worse for someone looking for the best answer to the question?"

Comment: Microsoft does give some guidance on var. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx and the Implicitly Typed Local Variables section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think it's fine to use `var` where it makes the code easier to read, which for me would mean that the type that `var` is replacing must be completely obvious.

For example, this would be a good use of `var` (contrived example):

```
var thing = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

However this would be a bad use of `var`:

```
var thing = GetThingFromDatabase();
```

Comment: what about a refactoring: GetThingFromDatabase returns for example 'Thing' object so you write:
Thing thing = GetThingFromDatabase();
instead of var thing ...
some time later you decided to turn Thing object into interface, and you have to change Thing to IThing everywhere ) my congratulations!

I would like to see how you will implement case when GetThingFromDatabase returns some mindblowing linq ;)

Answer (score 12):

I find it helpful in some cases where the type declaration is very long, for example:

```
Dictionary<int, string> item = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

becomes

```
var item = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Answer (score 8):

It amounts to the same thing because using the var keyword, the variable is implicity typed and the compiler infers the type at build time. I prefer to specify the type rather than use var in most cases, so I change my resharper settings.

Comment: -1: The questioner hows that and wants to know the basis on which would go about deciding which way to fall.

Comment: I don't think my answer is useless and deserves a downvote though

Comment: Fine, downvote undone - seems others are of a similar view (or are they trying to counter my 'nastiness' ? I gave it the -1 to counter a single +1 at the time -- I believe answers that dont add much arent the end of the world as long as they stay at zero and dont potentially make it take longer to get to an answer that actually has something insightful to say. IOW There's a reason why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205329/c-var-keyword-usage/1205396#1205396 has my +1 and others' too.

Comment: Personally I'd only downvote wrong or misleading answers, its up to you though. The question is about best practise anyway so the answers are going to be subjective. I said I prefer explicity types variables in most cases. As codespeaker says, it can look neater when the type decleration is long, I'd probably use var in that case to improve readability.

Comment: What I was getting at is that on a 'best practice' question where the answer is really 'it depends', saying yes or no is not enough - it needs to be "I always choose Y/N because ....[, even though I know some people say ... - which I disagree with because ...".  The Resharper settings point is a unique and useful point in this context though .... I'll actually flip flop and go +1 on that basis upon mature reflection!

Answer (score 1):

As i remember it Resharper just says that it could be written this way. It doesn't say that you should.

Alot of suggestions is just suggestions which I turned of the first time i saw them.. That being one of them.

Another was that it said was that it is redundant to write "this.someProperty", while i think the code gets easier to read by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper also has suggestion to transform if statement to true or not true.
Almost the same thing, but it depends on your style of coding.
So, when you find using var more comfortable - use this suggestion.