# Are implicitly-typed variables the way forward (C#)

Tags: c#, var, implicit-typing

I am using StyleCop for Resharper on a project originally written for .net v2. But I've since upgraded this project for 3.5 framework.

Stylecop is recommending I change the bulk of my explicitly typed variables to implicitly typed for example:

string - var

custom strong type - var

Is this the way forward when working with a .net 3.5 project. It seems unusual declaring everything as var.

Feel free to update the question title if my terminology is out...

Comment: Related/Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032/should-i-always-favour-implictly-typed-local-variables-in-c-3-0

Comment: Those aren't generics. Those are implicity typed local variables. Generics are of the form SomeClass<T> or SomeMethod<T>()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not generics, those are implicitly typed variables. This is really largely a matter of taste. There are places where you can overdo the use of [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) and there are places where it's very clearly necessary (think anonymous types) so just find the place in the middle that suits your (and your team's) preference.

Answer (score 3):

Been debated in many places, and it's down to taste. Compare these two lines of code:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

Which do you prefer?

Comment: That one is obvious but when it comes to `var foo = 0m;` I'd be more careful.

Comment: Correct. And tools like ReSharper won't suggest var for that sort of declaration.

Comment: Why would you be more careful with `var foo = 0m;`? Surely that unambiguously declares a `decimal` variable?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this

[var (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)  and

[Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

> An implicitly typed local variable is
>   strongly typed just as if you had
>   declared the type yourself, but the
>   compiler determines the type.

Also have a look at [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c)

and [C# Debate: When Should You Use var?](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/CSharp-var)

Answer (score 0):

I believe its more of a suggestion and should be considered, but not necessarily implemented fully.

While personal I believe the best use of var is when the declaring/returning type is obvious, i.e:

```
var temp = "Test me now";
```

versus

```
var temp = GetTestData();
```

Also I really enjoy being able to declare generic types with less code:

```
    var test = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

versus

```
    Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

var is quite important when using e.g. anonymous types...

```
var cees = from c in Customers select new { c.Name, c.Birthdate };
```

Resharper will suggest to change all to var. For obvious definitions like

```
var c = new Customer();
```

I like to use it.
for some API call I may write down the type explicitly:

```
Customer c = repository.Get(1);
```